# React: avoid redirect to first step wizard when pressing back button in wizard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'll try to explain this as clearly as possible.

I have a wizard component that works like this:

1. I open the wizard and fetch all the steps
2. Then I redirect to the first step by using the React Route

```
<WizardContext.Provider value={providerValue}>
  <CollectionContext.Provider value={collectionValue}>
    <Routes>
      <Route path={`:step*`} element={<StatusSteps steps={steps} />} />
      <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to={encodeURIComponent(steps[0].name)} />} />
    </Routes>
  </CollectionContext.Provider>
</WizardContext.Provider>
```

[image]

The problem with this is that when I press the back button of my browser in that first step, it will return to the root and thus do the same thing again and redirect to step[0].

How can I make sure that when I press the back button in the first step, that I will exit the wizard and go to the place before the wizard was opened?

Note: the first step of the wizard will always be different, so I can't just put code in a step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root route should actually redirect, e.g. REPLACE, to the wizard step instead of navigate, e.g. PUSH, to it. This replaces the current entry in the history stack with the first step in the wizard. If the user is on step "one" and issues a back navigation they will navigate back to the path they were on *prior* to navigation to the `"/"` route that redirected into the wizard.

You do this by specifying the `replace` prop on the `Navigate` component.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path=":step" element={<StatusSteps steps={steps} />} />
  <Route
    path="/"
    element={(
      <Navigate
        to={encodeURIComponent(steps[0].name)}
        replace // <-- REPLACE action
      />
    )}
  />
</Routes>
```